# How can I see the result value in shading?

Tags: shaders

[image]

The number 2 obeject of value is 2. 1 is less than 2.
you look at the nodes below.0.5 value plus 0.5 value can be seen. fac is 0.5
So I don't know what the result is. I can tell from the color that it is less bright.
I don't know what percentage of color 2 is and what percentage of color 1 is when the fac is 0.5.
Can I get the exact figures if I debug?

Comment: the result is `color1 + fac * color2`... is it what you wanted to know? Though, this result is modified by color management when rendered (so color picker won't give you the same result).

Comment: i wnat to know principle of mix rgb. I got a formula of mix rgb.. it's done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I used color picker.. it is useful

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use Math nodes. If the material output is white, the value is inside of the range. Carefully change the value to find the range of value.

Maybe there is more precise way to find value.

Comment: I want to see number.. but i find way that i see color. it is using of color picker. thank you for answer